# Google Analytics / Google Tag Manager - track user engagement time

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to track user engagement time of certain Content / Elements on my website.
You can see an example in the Movie "The social Dilemma" (Netflix) at 16:47.

I tried to implement this with Google Tag Manager, but all I achieved is the reading time of an entire page by tracking Header engagement and footer engagement.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can track scroll percentages of a specific content element.

The way to make this work is to first calculate the height of the HTML element that contains the content whose scroll depths you want to track. Then, you need to check how far from the top of the page this element is. Finally, you need to tell the Scroll Depth trigger to track pixel thresholds that correspond with the desired depths of the content element, and add the distance to the top of the page to those numbers:

[image]

You can find the guideline in Simo Ahava's blog:

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/customize-scroll-depth-trigger/#4-track-scroll-percentages-of-a-specific-content-element

By sending an event when each threshold is reached, the time between one event and another will be calculated in a more specific way, excluding the header and footer in the calculation of the engagement.